# The import com.xom.dm.mulesoft.AbstractInputTransformer cannot be resolved

Tags: java-8, mule, maven-3, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am new to the Mulesoft and Java. We have a Mule application in Mule 3.9.1, jdk8 and Maven 3.8.4. I am getting below errors could you please help to resolve the Anypoint Studio setup issues.

```
The import com.xom.dm.mulesoft.AbstractInputTransformer cannot be resolved

The method getFunctionalMap(String) of type PlannerGroupsInputTransformer must override a superclass method

Unable to find type 'org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException'
```

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xom.dm.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>dm-10-notifications</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <mule.version>3.9.1</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
        <munit.version>1.3.8</munit.version>
        <mule.munit.support.version>3.9.1</mule.munit.support.version>
        <service.instance>${instance}</service.instance>
    </properties>
```

I have tried changing build path and jre libraries... nothing works.

Comment: Where are you seeing those messages? In Studio error tab the console log, other? When editing, when building the application or when trying to execute? Are you providing the complete text of the messages? Please add to your question the source for the Java code mentioned and the pom.xml. FYI it is unlikely that this is a problem related to Studio setup or JDK/JRE libraries. It is much more likely a problem in the configuration of your project or Maven environment. Also saying 'I am new to the Mulesoft' would only make sense if you are a new MuleSoft employee. Did you meant Mule development?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the project is not correctly configured to build with [Anypoint Studio 6 built-in Maven support](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/6/using-maven-in-anypoint-studio). That you are trying to configure manually the build path is a tip that something is wrong for a Maven based project. Studio should configure the build path automatically from the pom. You must not change it manually. Read the documentation pages for that feature that I shared above and all its child pages to learn how to use a Maven project correctly in Studio 6.